# source control \ disadvantage of generating class with XSD

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

assume this - I want to read and write XML in a predefined scheme - till now it's ok.

The thing is that there is explicit action a developer needs to do case he wants to add another attribute (xsd.exe for example) and it's quite frustrating in teerms of source control (need to check out, generate new file, and check that in).

Is there a way to read xml just by supplying its XSD (without the need to actually auto-generate a class for that?) - in that case if new field will introduce - developer will change only the XSD or something?

Comment: mm - maybe I'll put the auto generatetion as part of my build in VS2010? though I still want to maintain only the flat xsd file in the source control...

Comment: Do you actually use the generated class? If so, there is not really a way around it. And why is it so bad that a generated file is updated along with the XSD when there are changes? The generated file(s) can be ignored when you are comparing/merging.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below link,

This can be the solution for this problem.

But please keep in mind that using xsd.exe is robust way to generate the classes for schema.

You can generate the class code form xsd on the fly and you can compile the code and use in your application

[How to programmaticly generate .NET classes from XSD? (Like xsd.exe do)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068260/how-to-programmaticly-generate-net-classes-from-xsd-like-xsd-exe-do)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlcodeexporter

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/650ax5cx.aspx